# Compile libgnat to a single LLVM bitcode file

Tags: ada, llvm-ir, gnat

How can I compile libgnat to a single LLVM bitcode file? The latest dragonegg release is very old, so I provide a dockerfile to make testing more easy. My end goal is to run Ada in LLVM IR bitcode interpreters.

**Dockerfile for the latest official dragonegg release**

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

COPY . /usr/src/workdir
WORKDIR /usr/src/workdir

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install build-essential gnat-4.6 libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev libz-dev gcc-4.6-plugin-dev
    # libz-dev for ld when compiling dragonegg 3.3
    # gcc-4.6-plugin-dev needed when compiling dragonegg 3.3

RUN tar -xzf gcc-4.6.4.tar.gz \
    && cd gcc-4.6.4 \
    && mkdir build \
    && cd build \
    && CC=gcc-4.6 ../configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=ada,c,c++ --prefix=/opt/gcc-4.6.4 \
    && make -j4 \
    && make install

RUN tar -xzf clang+llvm-3.3-amd64-Ubuntu-12.04.2.tar.gz \
    && mv clang+llvm-3.3-amd64-Ubuntu-12.04.2 /opt/llvm-3.3

ENV PATH="/opt/llvm-3.3/bin:/opt/gcc-4.6.4/bin:${PATH}"

RUN tar -xzf dragonegg-3.3.src.tar.gz \
    && mv dragonegg-3.3.src dragonegg-3.3 \
    && cd dragonegg-3.3 \
    && GCC=/opt/gcc-4.6.4/bin/gcc make \
    && cp dragonegg.so /opt/dragonegg.so
```

[download gcc-4.6.4.tar.gz](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.6.4/gcc-4.6.4.tar.gz)

[download clang+llvm-3.3-amd64-Ubuntu-12.04.2.tar.gz](https://releases.llvm.org/3.3/clang+llvm-3.3-amd64-Ubuntu-12.04.2.tar.gz)

[download dragonegg-3.3.src.tar.gz](http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/dragonegg-3.3.src.tar.gz)

**hello.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Hello is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Hello world from Ada (dragonegg)!");
end Hello;
```

Run `gcc hello.adb -S -O1 -o hello.ll -fplugin=/opt/dragonegg.so -fplugin-arg-dragonegg-emit-ir` to compile the hello.adb file. When I try to build the binary with `llc -filetype=obj hello.ll` and `gcc hello.o`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
hello.o: In function `_ada_hello':
hello.ll:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `ada__text_io__put_line__2'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error message indicates that the Ada runtime library is missing. Currently, I have no idea, how I can compile the libgnat to a single LLVM bitcode file, so I can link it with the program.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using DragonEgg? That's well and truly dead! See https://github.com/AdaCore/gnat-llvm instead.